# stream_socket_client timeout between containers when using PhpStorm Run

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, docker-compose, stream-socket-client

I have issue with `stream_socket_client()` function, but only under some circumstances.

I'm using docker-compose to build environment containing nginx, php-fpm (7.1.3), and schickling/mailcatcher (and a couple of other not important containers).

My problem relates to SwiftMailer, but I've isolated the issue to the following code:

```
// /var/www/web/app_dev.php
$streamContext = stream_context_create();
$timeout = 5;
$_stream = stream_socket_client('172.21.0.106:1025', $errno, $errstr, $timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
var_dump($_stream);
```

`172.21.0.106:1025` is correct and **static** IP:port for Mailcatcher.

Now, if I request this file via browser, I get:

> /var/www/web/app_dev.php:8:resource(4, stream)

which is correct.

When I do `docker exec php_container /var/www/web/app_dev.php`, I get:

> /var/www/web/app_dev.php:9:
>      resource(20) of type (stream)

which is also correct.

But when I run this script via PhpStorm (option 'Run >Run...') using configured Docker remote interpreter (working fine in general), I get output:

> docker://php_container:latest/php /var/www/web/app_dev.php
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
>   172.21.0.106:1025 (Connection timed out) in /var/www/web/app_dev.php on line 5
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0001     349080   1. {main}() /var/www/web/app_dev.php:0
>       0.0032     360960   2. stream_socket_client() /var/www/web/app_dev.php:5
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

I did some tests and it looks like the problem exists when trying to use any other container's host:port, but it's working when using anything outside of docker network.

For example using `'172.21.0.103:3306'` (MySQL container) the issue remains, but with `'google.com:80'`, it works also via PhpStorm Run feature.

Important part of docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  php:
    build: ./docker/php
    container_name: php_container
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
    networks:
      mynet:
        ipv4_address: 172.21.0.102

  mailcatcher:
    image: schickling/mailcatcher
    container_name: mailcatcher
    ports: 
      - "1080:1080"
    networks:
      mynet:
        ipv4_address: 172.21.0.106
networks:
  mynet:
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 172.21.0.0/24
```

PHP Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git zlib1g-dev zip unzip libgd-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql zip gd
RUN docker-php-ext-configure opcache --enable-opcache && docker-php-ext-install opcache

RUN pecl install xdebug-2.5.0 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

WORKDIR /var/www
```

It would be pretty much of content to put `docker-compose.yml`, all `Dockerfile`s etc here, so if any other specific part of configuration would be required, just let me now in the comment.

Comment: docker-compose is not dupported in phpstorm yet. Please vote https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137765

Comment: @AlexBlex it doesn't relate to my issue.

Comment: php storm spins up a single container without any network configs from docker-compose, hence connection timeout.

Comment: that make sense ;-) So that's why there's only **image** specified in the remote PHP Interpreter config, and not the **container**.

Comment: Also: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-33800 -- see if "duplicate all settings (volumes, networks, etc.) from docker-compose.yml inside PhpStorm" will help you here (not ideal by any means .. but worth checking out, at least for now).